# How can the MassTransit Error pipe be monitored to enable alerting?

Tags: masstransit

Is there a way to monitor the amount of messages in the Error and Skipped Pipe?

This way, our monitoring tool can poll the health check endpoint of our service, and that endpoint can the check if there are any messages on the error or the skipped queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon your message broker, you should setup your monitoring tool to look at the broker to check queue depths. There is no provision in MassTransit to do this monitoring for you.

Comment: I can add that most of the ops monitoring tools have integrations with popular message brokers. It is important not only to monitor error and skipped queues but also endpoint queues to get alert when the queue size starts to grow, an indicator that the consumer isn't coping with the load.

Comment: Ok, thanks for both answers. Makes perfect sense, to  monitor the broker seperately, instead of monitoring the queues via a producer or consumer.